# Probability of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to compute $P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n)$, where $X_i$ are independent samples from a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda>0$ and $x_i$ are nonnegative values.

$$P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n\mid X_1+\cdots+X_n=x_1+....+x_n)=\frac{P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_n=x_n)}{P(X_1+\cdots+X_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n)}\;,$$ the numerator part is simple, but I have no idea for the denominator part; it looks like a sample mean to me, but I still do not know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, each with Poisson($\lambda$) distribution, then the sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ has Poisson($n\lambda$) distribution, so your denominator is simply
$$\frac{e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^{x_1+\cdots+x_n}}{(x_1+\cdots+x_n)!}$$